# Error while closing streamwriter with json content type

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, streamwriter

I am having error closing streamwriter after writing json content to the stream writer.
Following is the code i am using. Can not find what is wrong. it is writing to REST service.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/EventLog", restPath));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = jsonstring.Length;                
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write(jsonstring);                
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Exception:"Cannot close stream until all bytes are written."

Comment: Try sw.Flush(); before closing

Comment: Already tried sw.Flush();, not working.

Comment: What's about `sw.BaseStream.CanWrite?`

Comment: the value of sw.BaseStream.CanWrite is true at run time and with that the close method is giving same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `request.ContentLength` is *really* equal to the Content lenght (in bytes).

This throws the same error:

```
string data = "mydata";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.de/");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = data.Length + 1;
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
sw.Write(data);
sw.Close();
sw.Dispose();
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```